# The getter 'velocity' isn't defined for the type 'JoystickComponent'

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

I'm trying to make a Joystick

```
class JoystickPlayer extends SpriteComponent with HasGameRef {
  JoystickPlayer(this.joystick)
    : super(
        anchor: Anchor.center,
        size: Vector2.all(100.0),
      );

  /// Pixels/s
  double maxSpeed = 300.0;

  final JoystickComponent joystick;

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    sprite = await gameRef.loadSprite('layers/player.png');
    position = gameRef.size / 2;
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    if (joystick.direction != JoystickDirection.idle) {
      position.add(joystick.velocity * maxSpeed * dt);
      angle = joystick.delta.screenAngle();
    }
  }
}
```

But I get a compile error:

> The getter 'velocity' isn't defined for the type 'JoystickComponent'

I'm using Flame 1.8.2  [link](https://docs.flame-engine.org/latest/flame/inputs/other_inputs.html)

Comment: As of Flame version 1.8.2, the JoystickComponent does not directly provide a `joystick.velocity` property. Instead, you can calculate the velocity by yourself. Based on the joystick's position changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JoystickComponent` doesn't have a velocity field, it does have a `relativeDelta` field that you can use though, which is the percentage and direction that the knob is from the center of the joystick to the edge.

So for example if you pull the knob completely to the right the `relativeDelta` would be `Vector2(1.0, 0.0)`, and completely to the left, `Vector2(-1.0, 0.0)`.

So you can use it quite similarly to how you tried:

```dart
  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    if (!joystick.direction != JoystickDirection.idle) {
      position.add(joystick.relativeDelta * maxSpeed * dt);
      angle = joystick.delta.screenAngle();
    }
  }
```